# Drive American car with American plates go the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, car, vehicle-registration, imports

I want to drive my car from Italy to my house in London but I have still american plates and in Italy I had never problems with that! However, the information on [gov.uk website](https://www.gov.uk/importing-vehicles-into-the-uk/temporary-imports) is so confusing because they wrote that I must ask a temporary permit but that's only for non EU residents!

I'm Italian resident. My car is sign to my cousin in Texas and I have texan registration plates. Can I drive in the UK?

Comment: Are you or will you become a resident in the UK? Do you want to (or perhaps have to) import the car there? As far as I can tell, the page you linked to does not say anything about EU residents but only about EU-registered cars (although the assumption would be that EU residents generally have EU-registered cars!)

Comment: I don't see what part of the linked documentation is confusing you.

Answer (score 2):

The information on the UK government web site you linked seems clear to me. I suspect you have simply misread it.

The relevant part appears to be:

> ## Customs relief for non-EU vehicles
>
> You may be able to claim relief from customs charges if your vehicle is registered outside the EU and you’re bringing it to the UK temporarily. This is known as ‘[temporary admission](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/notice-308-temporary-admission-temporarily-importing-non-eu-means-of-transport)’.
>
> Fill in [form C110](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/import-and-export-temporary-admission-notice-of-arrival-of-a-non-eu-private-motor-vehicle-c110) and take your vehicle through the ‘nothing to declare’ channel when you arrive in the UK.

This doesn't apply to "non-EU residents", it applies to vehicles registered outside the EU (and Texas is quite far outside the EU).

Also you must make sure that the vehicle's [inspection and registration sticker](http://twostepsonesticker.com/) is current before you go.

You must not be bringing the vehicle to the UK in order to sell the vehicle there or to establish residence in the UK and must export it again in order to qualify for the customs relief. And as the page also mentions, you will need the customs relief form if you are stopped by police.